# Regular Expression Code to Permit a Specific Pattern

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that I would like to validate a certain pattern for: Here's the string:

```
[alphanumeric characters at the start of the line, then->] ?,?,?,?,?[lines end with: vb|cr|crlf]
```

What I'd like to achieve as a validation would be to ensure the following, pertaining to the "`?,?,?,?,?`" string:

1. Validation should return false if there are more than one question mark (?) or comma (,) together. An example that should cause failure would be: `?? <or> ,, <or> ??? <or> ,,,`
2. Validation at the end of the line should just be for question marks (?) and commas (,). No other characters...
3. The last value in the string in question (which, again, is: `"?,?,?,?,?"`) should always be a question mark and not a comma.
4. Similarly, the start of this string should always be a question mark and not a comma.

I'm hoping that this would be possible with the preg_match function, but please let me know if it isn't possible.

Comment: When you write "[alphanumeric characters at the start of the line" does that mean no punctuation, and no white space, and should that be validated or is it irrelevant to the question?

Comment: Please can you add some sample patterns. To have better insights.

Comment: **Mark Byers**: I apologize; I mean that it can be a string that contains a-z / A-Z / 0-9 / (spaces) / opening and closing parenthesis. the vb|cr|crlf is just an end string, not to be interpreted as anything during the validation---it just happens to be included in the data **Laith Shadeed**: Here's a sample string. Pardon me for missing to include an actual sample: Read )Aloud Your Alphabet(?,?,?vb|cr|crlf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this regex? It matches your test case.

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9 ()]+(\?(?:,\?)+)?vb\|cr\|crlf$/i
                             ^
                             Added this question mark
```

Now, the regex matches:

1. `Read )Aloud Your Alphabet(?,?,?vb|cr|crlf`
2. `Read )In Silence Respect(vb|cr|crlf`

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HiMnOd) (This demo omits the above added question mark)

Comment: Hi **nickb**, I tried your regex and it worked right off the bat!.. There's just one thing I would like to ask... what if, instead of `Read )Aloud Your Alphabet(?,?,?vb|cr|crlf`, where the `?,?,?` is provided, we get instead `Read )In Silence Respect(vb|cr|crlf` which does not have the `?,?,?` (still following the original "validation guidelines" provided in my posted question but would be valid even without any `?` or `?,?` sequences? So sorry to bother you with this.. It's just so so close already... Thank you for your time

Comment: @NonymIty - If `Read )In Silence Respect(vb|cr|crlf` should match, then you just need to make the capturing group optional by suffixing it with a question mark - I've updated my answer with the fix.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, **nickb**! So far, all my testing has gone smoothly! I actually tried to do it myself, but I misplaced the ? _inside_ the group for checking the ?'s and ,'s --Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression:

```
"/[^,]\?(?:,\?)*vb\|cr\|crlf$/"
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/nntsr)

Comment: Thank you for your reply; at the moment I m trying to make this work at the same time as Eugene's post with this string: Read )Aloud Your Alphabet(?,?,?vb|cr|crlf

Comment: Does the string *literally* end with `"vb|cr|crlf"`?!! I think you may have misunderstood something (or I have).

Comment: Hi **Mark Byers**, I'm so sorry to be confusing.. What I do mean is that the string must always have the entire-> `vb|cr|crlf` at the end of it.. I appreciate all the help.. I'm unable to reply immediately because I'm trying to check and play around a bit with yours and **Eugene**'s code.. So sorry for the delays...

Comment: Thanks to everyone who posted. I went with the post of **nickb** .. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:

```
echo preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\s\(\)]+(\?,)+\?vb\|cr\|crlf$/', $string);
```

?

Comment: Thank you for your reply; I'm trying this one out with the following string: Read )Aloud Your Alphabet(?,?,?vb|cr|crlf

Comment: Thank you! I am trying this against other string samples that I have.. Sorry for the late replies..